# Reversing a string including the first letter in python

Tags: python, string, reverse

I am trying to reverse a string in python but i cannot include the first letter.

I tried this code:
a = "Helloworld"
print(a[3:0:-1])

but it doesn't work.
I also tried:
a = "Helloworld"
print(a[3:-1:-1])

It displays nothing when i try this.

Comment: Try this: print(a[::-1])

Comment: What is the number `3` in your attempts?

Comment: Numbers 3 is the end point but starting from end of string.

Answer (score 1):

The code you tried doesn't work because the slice a[3:0:-1] starts at index 3 and goes all the way to index 0 (in reverse), but it includes index 0, which is the first letter of the string.

The slice a[3:-1:-1] starts at index 3 and goes to the index before the last one (-1), but in reverse. This would give an empty string because the step value of -1 goes in the opposite direction of the start and end indices.

To reverse the string excluding the first letter, you can slice it like this:

```
a = "Helloworld" 
print(a[1:][::-1])
```

Comment: In "but it includes index 0", did you mean *excludes*?

Comment: or `print(a[::-1][:-1])` both do the same in a different order